# Ember destroyRecord on polymorphic record calls the wrong route

Tags: ember.js, polymorphism, ember-data

I have a polymorphic record type in my ember application. Posts has a polymorphic association called response, which can be a few kinds of response.

```
// post.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  responses: DS.hasMany('response', { polymorphic: true })
});
```

The response model is the basis for all the other types.

```
// response.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post'),
  message: DS.attr('string')
});
```

For example, a comment inherits from response.

```
// comment.js
import Response from '../models/response';

export default Response.extend();
```

This works perfectly for loading models using ember-data. It correctly connects to `/responses` on the Rails server for all types of responses.

However when I try to delete a record using `record.destroyRecord()` it sends the delete to `/comments` on the server, instead of `/responses`. Because this is a polymorphic record there is no `comments` route on the server.

Is there some other part of ember-data where I can indicate the record deletion should be polymorphic?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `adapter` part of ember.  In the `adapter` you can specify the endpoints for your calls.

---

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/customizing-adapters/
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

make sure youre referencing the same version of your ember app.

---

the `buildUrlMixin` is great for custimizing the urls for specific actions
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.BuildURLMixin.html

---

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'api/1'
});
```